# How to reflect change made in a component's variable to the view in Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, checkbox

I have (n) check boxes and a button in my angular2 view . When I click on one of them a function is called. When I click on the button every checkbox must be unchecked. How to do it?? (n) may vary dynamically.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpkea.png)

Comment: Please add the code to your question that demonstrates what you tried to accomplish, what you tried and where you failed.

Comment: there is a lot of code and not possible to post it here. Please refer to the image. On clicking the category1 all the checkboxes must be unchecked

Comment: Give some of your implemented code.

Comment: Nobody (literally) here is interested in a lot of code. Your problem can easily be reduced to 20 lines of code which can posted here. You also can use different names so nothing from your company will be revealed. StackOverflow is not a free coding service. It is required that you show  some effort and provide the information that allows to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Don't give me the code. Just tell me how can I change the checkbox to checked or unchecked by calling a function in the component.

Comment: You `<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="foo">` and toggle `foo` between `true` and `false`

Comment: I used ngModel, but its two way binding and checks all the checkboxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will give you an example from a table, since I have no idea what your code actually looks like, but it should work for what you need.

You need some object defined for all of your checkboxes. They likely all have certain properties in common, like labels. Here is an example of such an object:

```
myData = {
    content: [
        {
            some_string: '',
            some_number: 0,
            type: '',
            selected: false
        }
    ]
};
```

With this object you can create checkbox instances and push each one to an array, which will hold all of your checkbox objects.

Create your checkboxes in your html in a loop using the objects you have defined above. In your html have your checkboxes call a function. In the case below the `checkToggle()` function is called.

```
<input id='{{row.id}}' class='bx--checkbox bx--checkbox--svg' 
type='checkbox' name='checkbox' (change)="checkToggle($event, 
row.id)" [checked]="row.selected">
```

`checkToggle()` has been defined as follows:

```
//select or deselect this check box
checkToggle(event, nodeId) {
    const id = this.findNode(nodeId);
    this.myData.content[id].selected = !this.myData[id].selected;
}
```

Your button should end up calling a function to check all of the boxes

```
<button (click)="checkToggleAll($event)">Your Button Title</button>
```

Finally, have your `checkToggleAll()` function go through the entire array of checkboxes and set them. Here is an example:

```
//select or deselect all the check boxes
checkToggleAll(event) {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.myData.content.length; i++) {
        if (this.controls[this.myData.content[i].type]) {
            this.myData.content[i].selected = event.target.checked;
        }
    }
}
```

This is not something you can plug into your code but it should give you some idea of how to accomplish what you're after.